# Weird Laravel DB Listener make Query insert return wrong ID [SOLVED]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Im facing a weird maybe a bugs or my mistake where Eloquent create return wrong ID. It's happen when I put DB::listen in service provider class and store in database any queries detected in DB::listen.

BUT the weird is When i trying to insert like this `User::create($input)`, it's return the ID of `QueryActivity` not the ID of `User`. For example the ID should be 20 but its return 100 from table `QueryActivity`

logs from `User::create($input)`

[2020-02-23 12:42:46] staging.INFO: {"first_name":"Testing","last_name":"Tesgin","username":"Testing","staff_id":"12313123","mobile_phone":"01231232323","active":true,"email":"testing@gmail.com","created_by":1,"updated_at":"2020-02-23 12:42:46","created_at":"2020-02-23 12:42:46",***"id":123,***"fake_password":"5ebe2294ecd0e0f08eab7690d2a6ee69"}

Above Logs, the highlighted only the ID is wrong. Other detail is correct.

Eloquent

```
$user = User::create($input);
```

And in my ObserverServiceProvider.class

```
    DB::listen(function ($query) {
        try {
            if (preg_match('(query_activities)', $query->sql) == 0) {
                QueryActivity::createUsingQueryBuilder([
                    'connection_name' => $query->connectionName,
                    'time_taken' => $query->time,
                    'query' => $query->sql,
                    'bindings' => Utils::aesEncrypt(json_encode($query->bindings)),
                    'created_at' => now(),
                    'updated_at' => now(),
                ]);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            LogCentre::channel('query')->info($exception->getMessage());
        }
    });
```

in QueryActivity class

```
class QueryActivity extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'connection_name',
        'time_taken',
        'query',
        'bindings'
    ];


    public static function createUsingQueryBuilder(array $activity)
    {
        DB::connection((new self)->getConnectionName())->table((new self)->getTable())->insert($activity);
    }
}
```

Is there anyone facing this issues?

SOLUTION:

Based on issues in https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25768#issuecomment-424179984

Change connection name then its working..

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25768#issuecomment-424179984

Comment: hmm.. need to duplicate the connection, then its working.. what a weird cases